# const ddk = document.querySelector('#ddk > input'); doesnt work? just shows null in console

Tags: javascript, html, converters

I'm trying to make a currency converter but the querySelector is null i dont know how to fix it.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="valuta.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="valuta.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ddk">
            <input type="number" placeholder="DDK">
        </div>  

        <div id="usd">
            <input type="number" placeholder="DDK">
        </div>  

        <div id="eur">
            <input type="number" placeholder="DDK">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const ddk = document.querySelector('#ddk > input');
const usd = document.querySelector('#usd > input');
const eur = document.querySelector('#eur > input');

console.log(ddk);
```

Answer (score 1):

`const ddk = document.querySelector('.ddk > input');`

`#` matches id, `.` matches class.

```js
const ddk = document.querySelector('.ddk > input');
console.log(ddk);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="valuta.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="valuta.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ddk">
            <input type="number" placeholder="DDK">
        </div>  

        <div id="usd">
            <input type="number" placeholder="DDK">
        </div>  

        <div id="eur">
            <input type="number" placeholder="DDK">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CodeManiac null          valuta.js:2        i get this in the console

Comment: @Lasse you may need to listen to `document.onload`.